# DLINK-DKT-202-ES Setup

Tags: dlink

I recently bought a DLINK-DKT-202-ES from ebay. This device per my understanding is a modified DCS-2310L for use with a now bankrupt "Sage by Hughes" security system.

My understanding is the camera mentioned above should still have a built in webserver accessible via HTTPS. When I plug in the camera via ethernet, the ethernet port is showing up as on however the device is not obtaining an IP address from the DHCP server. Is this the expected behavior? If not, what can I do to further setup?

Comment: reset router to factory default

Answer (score 1):

Working through this I learned the device includes only a wired ethernet adaptor. Powering the device through the 5V port still requires a wire connection. The Wireless settings are encapsulated in the POE brick and therefore when the POE brick is not used there is no available WiFi.